# FormData doesn't work on upload files in React project with Redux and AXIOS when Its deployed

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, multipartform-data, form-data

I have a full MERN stack project with Redux and AXIOS. I used FormData to upload the images to my node server which has the multer and it works perfectly fine on my localhost even tho console on my chrome said empty? (FormData {}). When it's **deployed**, my FormData is empty. So I tested my FormData without the files(just the input value from forms) and it passes to the server and has it on req.body.

I tried to add config my formData and didn't work.

What am i doing wrong???

**For Example**

`config: { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } }` etc.....

**Here are some of my codes:**

**REACT Form JS**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import TextAreaFieldGroup from "../common/TextAreaFieldGroup";
import InputGroup from "../common/InputGroup";
import { addEventful, upload } from "../../actions/eventfulActions";

import Dropzone from "react-dropzone";

const imageMaxSize = 10000000
; //bytes
const acceptedFileTypes =
  "image/x-png, image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/gif";
const acceptedFileTypesArray = acceptedFileTypes.split(",").map(item => {
  return item.trim();
});

class EventfulForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      eventtitle: "",
      description: "",
      // comments:'',
      files: [],
      errors: {}
    };

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }


  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    if (newProps.errors) {
      this.setState({ errors: newProps.errors });
    }
  }

  verifyFile(files){
    if(files && files.length > 0){
      const currentFile = files[0]
      const currentFileType = currentFile.type
      const currentFileSize = currentFile.size
      if(currentFileSize > imageMaxSize){
        alert("TOO MANY FILES")
        return false
      }
      if (!acceptedFileTypesArray.includes(currentFileType)) {
        alert("IMAGES ONLY")
        return false
      }
      return true

    }
  }
  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { user } = this.props.auth;



    const formdata = new FormData();
    this.state.files.forEach((file, i) => {
      const newFile = { uri: file, type: "image/jpg" };
      formdata.append("file", file, file.name);
    });

    // const newEventful = {
    //   eventtitle: this.state.eventtitle,
    //   description: this.state.description,
    //   pictures: this.state.pictures,
    //   name: user.name
    // };

    formdata.append("eventtitle", this.state.eventtitle);
    formdata.append("description", this.state.description);
    formdata.append("name", user.name);

    this.props.addEventful(formdata);
    this.setState({ eventtitle: "" });
    this.setState({ description: "" });
    this.setState({ files: [] });
  }
  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  onDrop = (files, rejectedFiles) => {
    if(rejectedFiles && rejectedFiles.length > 0){
      console.log(rejectedFiles)
      this.verifyFile(rejectedFiles)
    }
    if (files && files.length > 0) {
      const isVerified = this.verifyFile(files)
      if(isVerified){
        console.log(files[0].name);
        const formdata = new FormData();
        files.map(file => {
          formdata.append("file", file, file.name);
        });
        // formdata.append("file", files[0], files[0].name);

        console.log(formdata);
        // this.props.upload(formdata);
        this.setState({
          files: files
        });
      }
    }
  };

  render() {
    const previewStyle = {
      display: "inline",
      width: 100,
      height: 100
    };
    const { errors, files } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="post-form mb-3">
        <div className="card card-info">
          <div className="card-header bg-info text-white">Create an Event</div>
          <div className="card-body">
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              <div className="form-group">
                <InputGroup
                  placeholder="Create a event title"
                  name="eventtitle"
                  value={this.state.eventtitle}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  error={errors.eventtitle}
                />
                {files.length > 0 && (
                  <Fragment>
                    <h3>Files name</h3>
                    {files.map((picture, i) => (
                      <p key={i}>{picture.name}</p>
                    ))}
                  </Fragment>
                )}
                <Dropzone
                  onDrop={this.onDrop.bind(this)}
                  accept={acceptedFileTypes}
                  maxSize={imageMaxSize}
                >
                  <div>
                    drop images here, or click to select images to upload.
                  </div>
                </Dropzone>


                <TextAreaFieldGroup
                  placeholder="Description"
                  name="description"
                  value={this.state.description}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  error={errors.description}
                />
              </div>
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-dark">
                Submit
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

EventfulForm.propTypes = {
  addEventful: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  errors: state.errors,
  eventful: state.files
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { addEventful, upload }
)(EventfulForm);
```

**My FormAction.js**

```
import axios from "axios";

import {
  ADD_EVENTFUL,
  GET_ERRORS,
  ADD_LIKE,
  REMOVE_LIKE,
  GET_EVENTFUL,
  GET_EVENTFULS,
  DELETE_EVENTFUL,
  CLEAR_ERRORS,
  EVENTFUL_LOADING,
  UPLOAD_FILES
} from "./types";

const config = {
  onUploadProgress: progressEvent =>
    console.log(
      "Upload Progress" +
        Math.round((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100) +
        "%"
    )
};
// Add eventful
export const addEventful = eventfulData => dispatch => {
  dispatch(clearErrors());
  // .post("/api/eventfuls", eventfulData, config)

  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/api/eventfuls',
    data: eventfulData,
    config: { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } }

  }).then(res =>
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_EVENTFUL,
        payload: res.data
      })
    )
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      })
    );
};
```

**node.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passport = require("passport");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

// Eventful model
const Eventful = require("../../models/Eventful");
const User = require("../../models/User");

// Validation
const validateEventfulInput = require("../../validation/eventful");
const validateCommentInput = require("../../validation/comment");

var multer = require("multer");

var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");

var btoa = require("btoa");

router.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
  })
);
router.use(bodyParser.json());

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, __dirname + "../../../uploads"); //you tell where to upload the files,
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now());
  }
});

var upload = multer({
  storage: storage
}).array("file");

router.use((request, response, next) => {
  response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  response.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  );
  response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
  next();
});

// @route   POST api/eventfuls
// @desc    Create eventful
// @access  Private
router.post(
  "/",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    upload(req, res, err => {
      console.log("req.body!!!!!", req.body);
      const { errors, isValid } = validateEventfulInput(req.body);

      // Check Validation
      if (!isValid) {
        console.log(errors);
        // If any errors, send 400 with errors object
        return res.status(400).json(errors);
      }

      console.log("req.files!!!!!", req.files);
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(404).json({
          uploadFailed: "Upload failed"
        });
      } else {
        let newArr = [];

        for (let file of req.files) {
          let fileReadSync = fs.readFileSync(file.path);
          let item = {};
          item.image = {};
          item.image.data = fileReadSync;
          item.image.contentType = "img/png";
          newArr.push(item);

          fs.unlink(file.path, function(err) {
            if (err) {
              console.log("error deleting image", file.path);
            } else {
              console.log("deleted image", file.path);
            }
          });
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
          var base64 = btoa(
            new Uint8Array(newArr[i].image.data).reduce(
              (data, byte) => data + String.fromCharCode(byte),
              ""
            )
          );
          newArr[i].image.data = base64;
        }

        console.log("33333333333333333333", newArr);

        const newEventful = new Eventful({
          title: req.body.eventtitle,
          description: req.body.description,
          pictures: newArr,
          user: req.user.id,
          name: req.user.name
        });

        newEventful.save().then(eventful => res.json(eventful));
      }
      console.log("skipped....................");
    }
  );
  }
);
```

**ERRORS/ LOGS on my PM2**

> 0|server   | 2019-01-13 21:27 -07:00: Server is ready to take messages
>   0|server   | 2019-01-13 21:28 -07:00: **req.body!!!!! [Object: null
>   prototype] {}** 0|server   | 2019-01-13 21:28 -07:00: **req.files!!!!!
>   []** 0|server   | 2019-01-13 21:28 -07:00: { [Error: ENOENT: no such
>   file or directory, open '/var/www/LCTW/uploads/file-1547440111023']
>   0|server   | 2019-01-13 21:28 -07:00:   errno: -2, 0|server   |
>   2019-01-13 21:28 -07:00:   code: 'ENOENT', 0|server   | 2019-01-13
>   21:28 -07:00:   syscall: 'open', 0|server   | 2019-01-13 21:28 -07:00:
>   path: '/var/www/LCTW/uploads/file-1547440111023', 0|server   |
>   2019-01-13 21:28 -07:00:   storageErrors: [] }

on here my req.body and req.files are empty.
**BUT**

when I commented out files parts out on my node.js, req.body exist!

```
0|server   | 2019-01-13 21:40 -07:00: req.body!!!!! [Object: null prototype] {
0|server   | 2019-01-13 21:40 -07:00:   eventtitle: 'asdfas',
0|server   | 2019-01-13 21:40 -07:00:   description: 'asdfads',
0|server   | 2019-01-13 21:40 -07:00:   name: 'In Soo Yang' }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see two problems in you code

**First** from the npm page of [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)

> This does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and
>   typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in
>   the following modules:
>
> 1. busboy and connect-busboy
> 2. multiparty and connect-multiparty
> 3. formidable
> 4. multer

So `body-parser` wont populate the `req.body` but since you are already using `multer` here is an example on how to populate the `req.body` with the `multipart/form-data`.

```
app.post('/', upload.none(), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.body contains the text fields
})
```

but since you need files and the above wont work you can use `upload.any()`

**Second** your middleware injection is in wrong order.

Change this

```
var upload = multer({
  storage: storage
}).array("file");
```

to

```
var upload = multer({
  storage: storage
})
```

And instead of

```
router.post(
  "/",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    upload(req, res, err => {

     //code

    }
  );
  }
);
```

do

```
router.post(
  "/",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  upload.array("file"), //or upload.any()
  (req, res) => {

    //....code
    //now req.body sould work
    //file should be at req.files

  );
  }
);
```

**EDIT 1**

Add in app.js or index.js or the start point of you app

```
global.rootPath = __dirname;
```

`global.rootPath` will now have the full path to your app. ex  `/usr/user/Desktop/myapp`
using `path,join(global.rootPath, "uploads")` will give you `/usr/user/Desktop/myapp/uploads`. 
The good thing using `path.join` is that it handles diffrent OS path systems like Windows and *nix

Always use `path.join` to create all the paths.

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, path.join(global.rootPath, "uploads")); //you tell where to upload the files,
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now());
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Its kinda working, now i have **new errors** on my pm2 logs, when i try to upload a picture.  `0|server   | 2019-01-14 02:56 -07:00: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/LCTW/uploads/file-1547459776817'` How come its looking for that file? isnt it supposed to look for **base64**?

Comment: with POST 500 ERROR

Comment: Is it something to do with my `var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, __dirname + "../../../uploads"); //you tell where to upload the files,
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now());
  }
});`?

Comment: @I.Y Well you do `fs.readFileSync(file.path);`  so supposedly if the file it not there then you should get `ENOENT` error. I suggest you always use [path.join](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths) to create paths!!. Also I suggest you do somethink like `global.rootPath = __dirname` at the index.js and avoid using `../../..`. Ideally it should look like  `path,join(__dirname, global.rootPath, "uploads")`

Comment: like this in my server.js?  `app.use(path.join(__dirname, global.rootPath, "uploads"));`i tried that i got bad gateway

Comment: Not exactly. I added the example int the answer. I accidently madate a copy-paste mistake in the comment

Comment: its `cb(null, path.join(global.rootPath, "uploads"))` its "." not "," right? well, I tried both and it has error saying `path.js:28
    throw new TypeError('Path must be a string. Received ' + inspect(path));`

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would like to add here is that You cannot console.log to the `FormData` Object.

eg:-

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('username', 'Rahul');
formData.append('username', 'Yogesh');

console.log(formData) // empty:- FormData {}
```

But that data will be sent to API. you can view that data in API Headers.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> config: { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } }
> ```

The multipart/form-data content type **must** specify the `boundary` parameter, which you can't know in advance.

Do not override the Content-Type that will be set automatically by XHR / fetch.

Comment: I tried with it and without it. its same. are you saying i need to set the boundary?

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used FormData() in my own React code to upload files, but for some reason that I cannot explain myself, the Files need to be appended last.  I am wondering if this has to do with the prior reply mentioning the requirement of a boundary parameter and an inability to know it until the actual upload happens.

Try appending your data first, then the files last.  I would also just try a single file as a test case.  Again, last.

Append these first:

```
formdata.append("eventtitle", this.state.eventtitle);
formdata.append("description", this.state.description);
formdata.append("name", user.name);
```

Then call this:

```
this.state.files.forEach((file, i) => {
  const newFile = { uri: file, type: "image/jpg" };
  formdata.append("file", file, file.name);
});
```

Hope it helps.  For the record, I also use multer, but I had the same issue while using multer on the server side.  Appending data prior to files was my required fix.

Regards,

DB

Answer (score 0):

when you use multer your image is stored in the file property of your request, so req.file, but you have req.files. Not sure if that is your only problem as I see others have commented on stackOverflow, but I think that is an issue as well. Do a console.log(req.file) and make sure I'm right, but I just used multer in my code as well and mine works.